# how to convert lat and longitude into distance near poles?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geometry, latitude-longitude, matlab

I am trying to convert latitude and longitude into meters in polar regions. I am looking for higher accuracy upto 0.00 meters preferably. I tried the haversine formula but it doesnt seem to be accurate enough for small increments in latitude. 
does anyone know a better formula that can be used near poles?

Comment: The Haversine formula will be extremely accurate, regardless of the latitude increments--for a spherical model. If you're having trouble with accuracy, that means you need to use an ellipsoidal datum. If you possibly can, choose a suitable projection so that ArcGIS does all the heavy calculations behind the scenes.  Otherwise, consider changing the spherical parameters to match a typical radius of curvature near the area of interest and apply the Haversine formula.